# Uniqueness of the maximal independent sigma algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

Given a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ and a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{H}\subset\mathcal{F}$, by Zorn's lemma, we can show that if there exists a nontrival sub-$\sigma$-algebra independent of $\mathcal{H}$, then there exists a maximal (nontrivial) sub-$\sigma$-algebra independent of $\mathcal{H}$. My question is:
Is this maximal sub-$\sigma$-algebra unique? If not, can you give a counterexample?

For a special case, given a random variable $X$ on a standard probability space, are all random variables independent of $X$ a measurable function of some random variable $Y$, namely $f(Y)$?

My proof to show existence of maximal sub-$\sigma$-algebra independent of $\mathcal{H}$:

Consider the set $A=\{\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}\mid \mathcal{G} \text{  independent of  }\mathcal{H} \}$ and it's nonempty. Then it's partially ordered with "$\subset$", every chain clearly has an upper bound which is the union of all elements in the chain. Thus by Zorn's lemma we claim the existence of the maximal element which is nontrivial.

PS: I know in many cases, there [might not even exist a nontrivial independent $\sigma$-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/q/54033) , but here let's talk about the case when there does exist.

Comment: I think that $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ is always in $A$, it feels like from your proof that this implies that there is always a maximal independent sigma algebra but I guess there is a problem with that reasoning.

Comment: I guess it is possible that it is the only element of $A$, in which case there is no RV $Y$ like you describe.

Comment: @P.Quinton Yes you are right. I should exclude trivial case in my question.

Comment: But it feels like even if there is an other element in $A$ there could be no RV $Y$ like what you described.